# visual c++ 2019 : typedef vector <class>, usage inside the class method

Tags: visual-c++

I'm developing a fleet management project using Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 (Professional).
returned to VC++ after several years and developing a library.
I have a class Vehicle and I need to group it using typedef vector

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
typedef vector<Vehicle> Fleet;   //error here. is it allowed to define like this in VS2019?

class Vehicle { 

  public: 
       Vehicle(unsigned id);
       void setVehiclesAvailable(Fleet& oldFleet) { 
         for(.... //iterate here to set availability for each vehicle in the old fleet.
       }
}
```

I'm getting compiler error 'Vehicle':undeclared identifier (in typedef)
Is there any alternate solution to define correctly?

Answer (score 2):

The error is due to `Vehicle` being undeclared at that point. You can forward-declare the `Vehicle` class before defining the `Fleet` type, like this:

```
class Vehicle;
typedef vector<Vehicle> Fleet;
```

Comment: thanks! I didn't see that I deleted that line.